# You don't have permission to access /betaSite/ on this server

Tags: html, apache

I'm having a big problem.  I just revamped this apt. companies website and created the new website in a folder contained in the current website.  I just finished and have put all of the old site files into and oldSite folder and brought all the new files out of the betaSite folder and into the public folder.  I've tried changing the file persmissions but idk if they are sticking.  Please help!  I really have no clue how to fix this.  Thanks!

asirentals.com

asirentals.com/index.shtml

Comment: Looks like your server doesn't recognize .shtml as a default page extension. You'll need to add it

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  So should I just change the extension to .html on the index page?  Or is there a way to make the server recognize it?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well you'll need to leave it as shtml if you have SSI content. If that is just a static page you can change it to html though. Check the link I posted below if you have access to you htaccess file. That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! With all your guys's assistance I have fixed the problem. I found the .htaccess file in dreamweaver and added 'index.shtml'. As mentioned, this allows apache to recognize and open .shtml files as the default file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/install-apache-2-windows.shtml

> If you want "index.shtml" to be your default start page for your directories, ie, if you want Apache to load "index.shtml" when you type "localhost" or "localhost/directory/", you will need to search for a line in your "httpd.conf" that begins with "DirectoryIndex" and add index.shtml to the list of files there. For example, modify it as follows:
>   DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html